# Proving $\mathbb{R}$ is connected via path connectedness

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

The standard proof given for the connectedness of $\mathbb{R}$ seems to me to be along the lines of [Understanding the proof of "connected set is interval."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398697/understanding-the-proof-of-connected-set-is-interval?rq=1).

A much simpler argument, I believe, is that $\mathbb{R}$ is pathconnected and hence connected ( open subsets of normed vector spaces are connected iff they are path-connected).

Why is the linked proof prefered ( or even stated) to this argument? Is my argument false/ less general? Many thanks.

Comment: I'd argue that it's more instructive as to what connectedness is: the proofs of very standard results like this are generally stated for pedagogical reasons, and this proof fits a general pattern that works on spaces that are not path connected too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that path-connected implies connected, in fact *relies* on the fact that $[0,1]$ is connected. And if you already know $[0,1]$ is connected you have already shown that $\Bbb R$ is connected too (it follows from general facts in ordered spaces; usual proofs use that bounded sets have sups etc., and proofs apply to both $[0,1]$ and $\Bbb R$ or any interval).

So proving $\Bbb R$ connected via path-connectedness is a **circular** argument.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your specified question, but for a connected space $X$ is equivalent:

I) $X$ is connected

II) $\emptyset$ and $X$ are the only sets that are open and closed

III) Every continuous map of $X$ into a discrete (finite) space is constant

IV) Every continuous map $X\to\{-1,1\}$ is constant

The proof is pretty short and simple.

So in my opinion the easiest argument for $\mathbb{R}$ beeing connected, is that $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are the only closed and open sets.

Comment: Interesting. But it seems non-trivial to me that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset$ should be the only clopen sets... Or am I being stupid?

Comment: @user No, you are not. But it is a very common result of the metric space $\mathbb{R}$ that only $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are closed and open (by 'default'). So I assumed, that you know this. I am pretty sure that this was shown in a beginners course in analysis that you have attempted and just have forgotten about it. However, it is not hard to proof. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628976/no-non-trivial-clopen-sets-in-mathbbr-how-to-give-a-direct-proof

Comment: Yes, it is clear that these sets are trivially clopen, but how do we guarantee that there is no other clopen set... ( I can prove it *once* I have proven connectedness, but that is obviously not the point).

Comment: I linked a proof of the statement in the comment above. It is rather simple and as I said a basic result, which implies connectedness of $\mathbb{R}$. I am aware, that my answer does not answer your initial question. I just wanted to give an easy alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the link. (edit. Just read the proof... yep you are right, easy enough)